# Emacs elpy Flymake can't find pyflakes even though pyflake has been installed by pip

Tags: python, emacs, pip, macports, flymake

After using macports pip-2.7 to install pyflakes, I can run it manually from the pip installation directory using the command line like:

```
python /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyflakes myfile.py
```

However, I'm trying to get my mac emacs environment setup with elpy, and flymake seems to not be able to find pyflakes, giving me a dialog when I open up a python file in elpy mode saying:

```
Flymake: Failed to launch syntax check process 'pyflakes' (with args myfile.py): Searching for program: no such file or directory, pyflakes. Flymake will be switched off.
```

I could go into /opt/local/bin and try to write my own executable file that runs the above python command. But that seems hacky and there must be a proper way to install/setup pyflakes such that flymake can find the command without manually creating wrapper scripts, isn't there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I can run it manually from the pip installation directory using the command line like:
>
> ```
> python /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyflakes myfile.py
> ```

Unless this directory is in your `$PATH`, Emacs has no way to know where to find `pyflakes`.

One option would be to create a symbolic link, e.g.

```
ln -s /opt/local/.../python2.7/site-packages/pyflakes /opt/local/bin/pyflakes
```

Of course, you will have to use the full path. I shortened it for readability. This is relatively common on Linux machines, though I don't know how broadly it is used on OSX.

Another option, one which I prefer, would be to reinstall `pyflakes` using [`pip install`'s `--user` option](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install.html#cmdoption--user):

> ```
> --user
> ```
>
> Install to the Python user install directory for your platform. Typically ~/.local/, or %APPDATA%Python on Windows. (See the Python documentation for site.USER_BASE for full details.)

`--user` is great for installing things that you might want to run independently of any particular project, like `pyflakes`. It installs things to your home directory instead of to a system directory, so you don't need any elevated privileges to use it.

You may have to add the user location to your `$PATH` variable, but you'll only have to do this once. Any future tools installed using `pip install --user` will become available immediately.

On my Linux machine, the directory that I had to add to my `$PATH` is `~/.local/bin/`.